# PHP array_slice not producing first 2 characters

Tags: php

I have a variable that when echo produces the following:

```
echo $userinfo['CoverageGroup']
```

Displays:  SAGotSA

I need to strip everything but the first two values in this case "SA".

I tried to perform the following but get an error:

> Warning: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

```
$output = array_slice($userinfo['CoverageGroup'], 0, 2); echo $output;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Functions with `array` in their name take arrays and functions with `str` take strings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$userinfo['CoverageGroup']` is a string.

You want [`substr()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$output = substr($userinfo['CoverageGroup'], 0, 2);
```

You can view the output here: https://3v4l.org/kVVpB#output